# Struts2 iterator to populate dropdown with different types

Tags: java, jsp, select, struts2, iterator

I have a Map whose key is a `String` and value may be either a `String` or another `Map` which depends on response returned from a Java file.

I need to populate that response in a drop-down using Struts2 iterator.

My requirement is, If the value is `String`, I need to use `<option>` tag. If the value is a `Map` I need to go for `<optgroup>`.

So, I need to check if the 'value' of that Map is `String` or `Map` and populate it correspondingly.

Comment: @user3271472 does your string have any format ?? so you can check contains Or equals method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just easy as it seems:

```xml
<select name="foo">

    <s:iterator value="myMapOfMaps" var="currentEntry">
        <s:if test="%{#currentEntry.value instanceof java.util.Map}">

            <optgroup label="<s:property value='%{#currentEntry.key}'/>">
                <s:iterator value="#currentEntry.value" var="innerEntry">

                    <option value="<s:property value='%{#innerEntry.key}'/>">
                        <s:property value='%{#innerEntry.value}' />
                    </option>

                </s:iterator>
            </optgroup>

        </s:if>
        <s:else>

            <option value="<s:property value='%{#currentEntry.key}'/>">
                <s:property value='%{#currentEntry.value}' />
            </option>

        </s:else>
    </s:iterator>

</select>
```